# Summing a list by using dolist macro

Tags: common-lisp

I was trying to sum a list by using dolist macro. But, I couldn't do it. It always returns the last element of the list. Thanks in advance.

```
(defun sumlist2 (l)
  ;;this function computes total of a list by using dolist macro
  (let ((summ 0))
    (dolist (obj l)
      (setf summ (+ obj)))
    summ))
```

Comment: FYI and fellow googlers, summation with loop and series: https://lispcookbook.github.io/cl-cookbook/iteration.html#summation

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In the body of `dolist`, you do not sum a value to the variable `summ`, but assign to it the value of the element of the list, since `(+ obj)` sums `obj` with no other value and so returns `obj` itself. In other words, instead of:

```
(setf summ (+ obj))
```

you should write:

```
(setf summ (+ summ obj))
```

or, even better:

```
(incf summ obj)
```

which performs the addition.

Finally note that you can produce a result directly from `dolist`, like in:

```
(defun sumlist2 (l)
  ;;this function computes total of a list by using dolist macro
  (let ((summ 0))
    (dolist (obj l summ)
      (incf summ obj))))
```

Answer (score 5):

The `+` function in Lisp is immutable, it just computes a new value:

```
(+)         is zero
(+ x)       is just x
(+ x y ...) is the sum of x, y, etc.
```

In your code, you `setf` the local `summ` variable with each values taken from the list.
Eventually, it contains only the last value of the list. If you want to update `summ`, you need to do:

```
(setf summ (+ summ obj))
```

Or, simply:

```
(incf summ obj)
```

Answer (score 2):

FYI with `loop`:

```
(loop for i in '(1 2 3) sum i)
;; 6
```

also

```
(reduce #'+ '(1 2 3))
```

see more: https://lispcookbook.github.io/cl-cookbook/iteration.html#summation

Answer (score 0):

Below I have an example of a function that can work for you, and then will explain your error:

```
(defun sum-list(lst)
  (let((sum 0))
    (dolist(l lst)
      (setf sum (+ sum l)))
     sum))
```

Instead of:

```
(setf sum (+ obj))
```

We add the sum of the list that we already acquired in the previous iteration to the number in the list that we are currently iterating through:

```
(sum-list ‘(1 2 3 4 5 6 7))
28
```

Below we can pass a list of the integers 1-7 which will return a value of 28.